# How can I get retrospective info on how often each of my outputcache fires?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'd like the ability to find out how often each output attribute/filter is being applied, so I need per action granularity and I would like my solution to be as efficient/scalable as possible. The perfmon counters (application-wide) (as answered below) are very handy, but I'd like the per action granularity.

1. I'd be open for a database solution, but it's not preferred, if I went down this route, how would I insert into the database (for when a response is cached), would I have to subclass Outputcache, and write some code in the constructor?
2. I'd also be open for logging something out to a file? But again it looks like I'd need to subclass.
3. I'd also be open to Google analytics type approaches, whereby the user response get's it back.
4. Is there a way to put a 'cached' marker in my http header? This could be used as an identifier as well.

Comment: and what have you done? or even tried?

Comment: As stated, this is just too broad (bounties don't solve the issue of question scope) - if you can narrow this down a bit I'm happy to reopen it.

Comment: Ok I have changed it, hope this is ok, thanks Tim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASP.Net Applications perf counters.  The ones relevant to your question are:

```
Output Cache Entries
Output Cache Hit Ratio
Output Cache Hits
Output Cache Misses
```

You can use perfmon's data collector feature to collect these perf counters for you as your application runs.

These are per-app, so you won't get the per-action granularity you ask for.